# How can I stabilize unstable voltages over a silicon plate?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, materials

I've been working on an experiment where I investigate the hall effect over a circular silicon plate. Here is the schematic[image: schematic]

The two channels of the oscope are placed between the plate. Each of the outputs are connected to the semiconductor via copper foil that connects to about a fourth of the disk with gaps between each connection. I'm expecting to see an increase in voltage when I place an electromagnet above the plate, but the problem is that the voltage across the plate keeps fluctuating between 100 mV- -50mV even when the magnet isn't there, so if the magnet is affecting the voltage I wouldn't be able to tell. I have an older ATX power supply connected to a boost buck converter supplying the 30Vs to the silicon plate. I'm measuring the voltage with an Analog Discovery Board 2. Is there something I should add to the circuit to stabilize the voltage or is it something to do with the nature of the silicon plate?

Comment: How stable is your 30 volt supply?

Comment: Carefully read [this NIST page](https://www.nist.gov/pml/nanoscale-device-characterization-division/popular-links/hall-effect/resistivity-and-hall) on the topic. It does identify some of the more serious issues. But not all of them. However, take a close look near the top where they show you various shapes and suggest which are "good" and which are "bad" for this measurement. Later, look over their procedures designed to deal with thermal variations, non-uniform experimental design and implementation, etc. How do your procedures compare? How does your design compare?

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful